# "open_basedir restriction in effect" but file is in the correct dir

Tags: php, iis, plesk

I am trying to move some sites to a new server (running Plesk 11) and I am getting the following Error:

> Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(configuration.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\domains\domain.com\www\;C:\Windows\Temp) in 
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\domains\domain.com\www\index.php on line 18

But the `configuration.php` file is in `C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\domains\domain.com\www\`!

I am nearly getting crazy here as this makes absolutely no sense to me.
I can even set the `open_basedir` value to `none` and still get the same error.
Same also for using PHP 5.2 or 5.3.

The only thing which got me a little bit further was setting a `dirname(__FILE__)` in front of the call in `index.php` on line 18, but this is no solution as I can't alter all file references in the whole CMS. Because of this I also tried to add the `www` folder to the include path without any luck.

Comment: Check your php include path: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php - which value does it have? Probably you need to add some other paths from there to the open_basedir setting? Also you might want to disable open_basedir, but that depends, see: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir - and what is the full path of configuration.php?

Comment: As said in the last paragraph it also didn't work with `.;./includes;./pear;C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\domains\domain.com\www ` as the include path.

Comment: And which CMS system is this? I would consider that this is worth of support request with the vendor. Might just be some wrong configuration on your end, might be a common problem with the CMS.

Comment: Its not a problem of the CMS (but one is Joomla! 1.0 for example), as this happens to EVERY php file access I try on that server. I have a few sites running using different CMS and some self written stuff and all have the same problem. I fixed it with the `dirname(__FILE__)` for my own scripts, but as said this is no general solution.

Comment: Check if `getcwd()` returns correct path (should be `C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\domains\domain.com\www\` )

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: I think you found the problem: I got `C:\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5` from `getcwd()` - how do I change this?

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK there has been a problem in Plesk with disabling `open_basedir` on Windows. Try to delete `open_basedir` key from registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\PHP\Per Directory Values\C\Inetpub\vhosts\yourdomain.com\httpdocs
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as I found out with the help of dev-null-dweller the actual problem is the working directory...

Comment: Word to Sergey above. Spent hours getting nowhere until I found this post. Clearing the "open_basedir" value in the registry worked. Next question is, why is it set in the first place?

Comment: Plesk put those entries in there without informing the user that their admin changes won't have any effect. This is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Somethings wrong with your php installation, check php.ini for correct values under windows: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php#example-42

If they are correct you should contact Plesk support

Comment: @chrfin: In FastCGI, setup the environment properly, including the working directory. It might be that you need to administer the system for that because Plesk might not offer any GUI for that. Just saying.

Comment: @hakre: Can you give me a hint where/how I can configure FastCGI as I already searched for that and didn't found anything?

Comment: There often is a script that takes care of that, and in that script you can change the working directory. You're using windows and IIS, so actually I must admit: No clue, sorry. Contact your vendor for documentation and technical support plans.

Answer (score 0):

For IIS, I've cracked my head until I added IUSR (or whatever the user server shows when you run  `echo get_current_user();`) to the `Windows\Temp` security tab.

Give that user [`read`] / [`write`] privileges on `Windows\Temp` and it should work.

Comment: Can you please explain where exactly is `Windows\Temp`

Comment: It is exactly at c:\windows\temp or d: or e: depending of the unit where you've installed windows.